# add custom tiles to geopandas dataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, cartopy

I know I can add custom background maps to a geopandas data frame like below

```
ax = df_wm.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
cx.add_basemap(ax, source=cx.providers.Stamen.TonerLite)
ax.set_axis_off()
```

How could I use other map tiles. For example, USGS topo tiles like those from the national map below?
https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/7/46/26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get webmap tiles for your maps' background from a standard sources, you need to identify `url` and `layer` and use them in your code. Here is a demo script that uses cartopy to request the services.

Map tiles are generally produced in `web-mercator` projection (ccrs.epsg(3857)). If you want to use them as is you must plot your map on that projection or mercator projection.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import geopandas as gpd

url = "https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml"
layer = "USGSTopo"

mercator = ccrs.Mercator()  #ccrs.epsg(3857)
nonproj  = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=mercator)

# The requested maps will appear as data that
#   matplotlib can plot on its `ax`
ax.add_wmts(url, layer)
ax.set_extent([20, 25, 35, 40], crs=nonproj)

# Plot a linestring using long/lat in degrees
ax.plot([20.1, 22.7, 24.5], [35.5, 37.2, 39.2], transform=nonproj ,zorder=15)

# Plot Geopandas cities data
city_pnts = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))

# Geometries in Geodataframes have CRS transformed
#  to Mercator projection and plotted here
cty2 = city_pnts.to_crs(mercator.proj4_init)
cty2.plot(ax=ax, color="red", zorder=20)

ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

ax.set_title('USGSTopo WMTS')
plt.show()
```

[image: wmts]